# How to reference a module variable in an expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a module and it's variable defined like this

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.value(
    'image',
    {
        id: null,
        url: null,
    }
);
```

In a module controller I set the variable to some value later on after an AJAX call. The actual value of the variable is set correctly as I check it from the controller after the call.

I try to reference this variable from the HTML code like this

```
<html ng-app="app">
...
<img ng-src="{{app.image.url}}">
```

For some reason the expression is evaluated into an empty string. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `app` is not defined in the `$scope`, you have to set it:

```
angular.module('app').controller('SomeController', function(image) {
    $scope.image = image;
});
```

then in your view:

```
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="SomeController">
...
<img ng-src="{{image.url}}">
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This worked for me. So the `ng-app="app"` does **not** create a reference `app` to the module, right? Also I've tried to add the entire module to the controller's scope like this `$scope.app = app` and reference the `app.image.url` but this did not work for some reason. Is it an expected behavior or I made something wrong?

Comment: yes, it is expected behavior, the view only "sees" variables defined in the `$scope`, you can also set something in the `$rootScope`, it will then be inherited by any child scope.